# get the list of menu items that are valid possible parents for the given menu item using menu_parent_options()

Tags: routes

I want to get the list of parents for a given menu item. As described at api.drupal.org  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21menu%21menu.module/function/menu_parent_options/7
I tried but i am not able to get all the parent of a menu item. As the second argument $item to this function should be menu item i tried this code. For example

```
<?php
$menu_name = array('management' => 'Management');
var_dump(menu_parent_options($menu_name, menu_link_load(23)));
?>
```

I want to get the parent list of menu /admin/appearance/list which have mlid = 23.
But this code give output

> array (size=1)   'management:0' => string '' (length=12)

but output should give /admin/ and /admin/appearance also in output in the form of

> menuname:mlid

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if it helps

```
<?php
$menu_arr = menu_get_menus();
echo '<pre>';print_r((menu_parent_options($menu_arr, 23)));
?>
```

Comment: No it didn't work, you have to pass menu $item argument which you get by menu_get_item(), passing menu link id(mlid) directly is same as menu_parent_options($menu_arr, 0)). It return the full tree including the item itself.